# Auto Redirect Visitors to the particular website

Tags: redirect, ip, ip-address, shopify

I have just discovered the code which is redirecting the visitors based on their IP address. For example if we want to redirect our visitors from example.in to example.com as ".in" is our local domain and ".com" is the international domain.

We want our customers to visit international website only who are from US, UK if they visit example.in.

The problem is if they are visting from mobile device, they are not getting redirected. Please help.

Sharing my code below :

```
<script>

  jQuery.ajax( {
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {
    // If the visitor is browsing from Foreign Country

  if (location.country_code == 'US' || location.country_code == 'ZA'))  {
      // Redirect to the International store.
      window.top.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
    }
  }
} );



  </script>
```

PS : I am placing the above code in example.in

Comment: What is ZA ?? ZA is not United Kingdom, it's South Africa. Check if mobile devices are getting logged. Put a console/alert function before this ajax call and inside success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also But I not tried this

```
<script type="application/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.getJSON("http://www.telize.com/geoip?callback=?",
 function(json) {
 // If the visitor is browsing from China.
 if (json.country_code === 'CN') {
// Redirect him to the China store.
 window.location.href = 'http://www.mydomainname.cn';
 }
 }
 );
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Sankar ! Thanks for your reply, actually the main problem is that the visitors are not redirecting if they are using mobile devices or smartphones, otherwise it is working fine for deskti

Answer (score 0):

Lets do with this http://jsfiddle.net/kvishnudev/7Ut65/1/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Get web visitor's location</title>
    <meta name="robots" value="none" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="yourinfo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAp04yNttlQq-7b4aZI_jL5hQYPm-xtd00hTQOC0OXpAMO40FHAxQMnH50uBbWoKVHwgpklyirDEregg"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Continent = {"AD":"Europe","AE":"Asia","AF":"Asia","AG":"North America","AI":"North America","AL":"Europe","AM":"Asia","AN":"North America","AO":"Africa","AQ":"Antarctica","AR":"South America","AS":"Australia","AT":"Europe","AU":"Australia","AW":"North America","AZ":"Asia","BA":"Europe","BB":"North America","BD":"Asia","BE":"Europe","BF":"Africa","BG":"Europe","BH":"Asia","BI":"Africa","BJ":"Africa","BM":"North America","BN":"Asia","BO":"South America","BR":"South America","BS":"North America","BT":"Asia","BW":"Africa","BY":"Europe","BZ":"North America","CA":"North America","CC":"Asia","CD":"Africa","CF":"Africa","CG":"Africa","CH":"Europe","CI":"Africa","CK":"Australia","CL":"South America","CM":"Africa","CN":"Asia","CO":"South America","CR":"North America","CU":"North America","CV":"Africa","CX":"Asia","CY":"Asia","CZ":"Europe","DE":"Europe","DJ":"Africa","DK":"Europe","DM":"North America","DO":"North America","DZ":"Africa","EC":"South America","EE":"Europe","EG":"Africa","EH":"Africa","ER":"Africa","ES":"Europe","ET":"Africa","FI":"Europe","FJ":"Australia","FK":"South America","FM":"Australia","FO":"Europe","FR":"Europe","GA":"Africa","GB":"Europe","GD":"North America","GE":"Asia","GF":"South America","GG":"Europe","GH":"Africa","GI":"Europe","GL":"North America","GM":"Africa","GN":"Africa","GP":"North America","GQ":"Africa","GR":"Europe","GS":"Antarctica","GT":"North America","GU":"Australia","GW":"Africa","GY":"South America","HK":"Asia","HN":"North America","HR":"Europe","HT":"North America","HU":"Europe","ID":"Asia","IE":"Europe","IL":"Asia","IM":"Europe","IN":"Asia","IO":"Asia","IQ":"Asia","IR":"Asia","IS":"Europe","IT":"Europe","JE":"Europe","JM":"North America","JO":"Asia","JP":"Asia","KE":"Africa","KG":"Asia","KH":"Asia","KI":"Australia","KM":"Africa","KN":"North America","KP":"Asia","KR":"Asia","KW":"Asia","KY":"North America","KZ":"Asia","LA":"Asia","LB":"Asia","LC":"North America","LI":"Europe","LK":"Asia","LR":"Africa","LS":"Africa","LT":"Europe","LU":"Europe","LV":"Europe","LY":"Africa","MA":"Africa","MC":"Europe","MD":"Europe","ME":"Europe","MG":"Africa","MH":"Australia","MK":"Europe","ML":"Africa","MM":"Asia","MN":"Asia","MO":"Asia","MP":"Australia","MQ":"North America","MR":"Africa","MS":"North America","MT":"Europe","MU":"Africa","MV":"Asia","MW":"Africa","MX":"North America","MY":"Asia","MZ":"Africa","NA":"Africa","NC":"Australia","NE":"Africa","NF":"Australia","NG":"Africa","NI":"North America","NL":"Europe","NO":"Europe","NP":"Asia","NR":"Australia","NU":"Australia","NZ":"Australia","OM":"Asia","PA":"North America","PE":"South America","PF":"Australia","PG":"Australia","PH":"Asia","PK":"Asia","PL":"Europe","PM":"North America","PN":"Australia","PR":"North America","PS":"Asia","PT":"Europe","PW":"Australia","PY":"South America","QA":"Asia","RE":"Africa","RO":"Europe","RS":"Europe","RU":"Europe","RW":"Africa","SA":"Asia","SB":"Australia","SC":"Africa","SD":"Africa","SE":"Europe","SG":"Asia","SH":"Africa","SI":"Europe","SJ":"Europe","SK":"Europe","SL":"Africa","SM":"Europe","SN":"Africa","SO":"Africa","SR":"South America","ST":"Africa","SV":"North America","SY":"Asia","SZ":"Africa","TC":"North America","TD":"Africa","TF":"Antarctica","TG":"Africa","TH":"Asia","TJ":"Asia","TK":"Australia","TM":"Asia","TN":"Africa","TO":"Australia","TR":"Asia","TT":"North America","TV":"Australia","TW":"Asia","TZ":"Africa","UA":"Europe","UG":"Africa","US":"North America","UY":"South America","UZ":"Asia","VC":"North America","VE":"South America","VG":"North America","VI":"North America","VN":"Asia","VU":"Australia","WF":"Australia","WS":"Australia","YE":"Asia","YT":"Africa","ZA":"Africa","ZM":"Africa","ZW":"Africa"};
    if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
        visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude;
        visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude;
        visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
        visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
        visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
        visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
        if(visitor_countrycode!= null)
        {
                var Cont = Continent[visitor_countrycode];
                //alert(Cont);              
        }

        //
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Lat/Lon: ' + visitor_lat + ' / ' + visitor_lon + '</p><p>Location: ' + visitor_city + ', ' + visitor_region +', Continent : ' + Cont + ', ' + visitor_country + ' (' + visitor_countrycode + ')</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Whoops!</p>';
    }
</script>
</body>
```